# Cannot find Substring "n't"

Tags: swift, string, substring

I am trying to determine whether an input string contains "n't" or "not".
For example, if the input were:

```
let part = "Hi, I can't be found!"
```

I want to find the presence of the negation.
I have tried input.contains, .range, and NSRegularExpression. All of these succeed in finding "not", but fail to find "n't". I have tried escaping the character as well.

```
'//REGEX:

let negationPattern = "(?:n't|[Nn]ot)"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: negationPattern)
    let results = regex.matches(in: text,range: NSRange(part.startIndex..., in: part))
    print("results are \(results)")
    negation = (results.count > 0)

} catch let error {
    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

//.CONTAINS
if part.contains("not") || part.contains("n't"){
    print("negation present in part")
    negation = true
}

//.RANGE (showing .regex option; also tried without)
if part.lowercased().range(of:"not", options: .regularExpression) != nil || part.lowercased().range(of:"n't", options: .regularExpression) != nil {
    print("negation present in part")
    negation = true
}
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot with code that you already tried - add the code directly in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, and the screenshot is actually what gives it away: your regex pattern has a plain single quote in it, but the input text has a "smart" or "curly" apostrophe in it. The difference is subtle:

- Regular: '
- Smart: ’

Lots of text fields will automatically replace regular single quotes with "smart" apostrophes when they think it's appropriate. Your regex, however, only matches the plain single quote, as evidenced by this tiny test:

```
func isNegation(input text: String) -> Bool {
    let negationPattern = "(?:n't|[Nn]ot)"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: negationPattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: text,range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
    return matches.count > 0
}

for input in ["not", "n't", "n’t"] {
    print("\"\(input)\" is negation: \(isNegation(input: input) ? "YES" : "NO")")
}
```

This prints:

```
"not" is negation: YES
"n't" is negation: YES
"n’t" is negation: NO
```

If you want to continue using a regex for this problem, you'll need to modify it to match this kind of punctuation character, and avoid assuming all your input text includes "plain" single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! I have set the textField input's smartQuotes to .no, and it works. Thanks again :)